# Could you find the issue with this neon cursor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please may i have a second view on this code. Something is wrong however I just cant seem to get this one right. Here is the link to the git post along with my code below
https://codepen.io/soju22/full/wvyBorP

I have tried importing three.js even though I know I dont need it. What I believe the issue to be is the javascript import of dependencies.

```js
import { neonCursor } from 'threejs-toys'

neonCursor({
  el: document.getElementById('app'),
  shaderPoints: 16,
  curvePoints: 80,
  curveLerp: 0.5,
  radius1: 5,
  radius2: 30,
  velocityTreshold: 10,
  sleepRadiusX: 100,
  sleepRadiusY: 100,
  sleepTimeCoefX: 0.0025,
  sleepTimeCoefY: 0.0025
})
```

```css
body, html, #app {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #app {
    overflow: hidden;
    touch-action: pan-up;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffffff, 0 0 20px #000, 0 0 30px #000;
  }
  
  #app h1 {
    --fontSize: 60px;
    --lineHeight: 80px;
    width: auto;
    height: calc(2 * var(--lineHeight));
    line-height: var(--lineHeight);
    margin: calc(50vh - var(--lineHeight)) auto 0;
    font-size: var(--fontSize);
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  #app a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  #app canvas {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>VD Capital</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/365cb50038.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="hero">
          <h1>NEON<br/>CURSOR</h1>
          <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/klevron/threejs-toys">github/threejs-toys</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably right and are importing wrong. As I understand, 'threejs-toys' doesn't exist locally on your system. Try changing import as:

```
import { neonCursor } from 'https://unpkg.com/threejs-toys@0.0.8/build/threejs-toys.module.cdn.min.js'
```